# How to schedule a cron job to run a video fill every 5 minute?

Tags: ubuntu, python, nano

I need to play a video file on vlc every 5 minutes daily.

Comment: `5 * * * * /path/to/my/video/player/script`

Answer (score 0):

The command you want to schedule should be something along the line of:

```
bash -c "DISPLAY=:0 cvlc $VLCOPTIONS"
```

and could be something like:

```
bash -c "DISPLAY=:0 cvlc Freedom\\ in\\ yor\\ computer\\ and\\ in\\ the\\ net.webm"
```

if you want it to be as easy as possible.

You can create a cron job as:

```
$> crontab -e
```

and then add

```
*/5 * * * * bash -c "DISPLAY=:0 cvlc $VLCOPTIONS"
```

Comment: vishal@vishal-HP-Notebook:/$ crontab -l
no crontab for vishal
vishal@vishal-HP-Notebook:/$ crontab -e
no crontab for vishal - using an empty one
crontab: installing new crontab

Comment: I assume you're trying to tell me that you don't have Cron installed? Try to install it and if you have further questions, please come back :)

Comment: No i have installed cron